# UITextView blurry layer when rendering in context

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have problem when rendering my UITextView in CGContext, it becomes blurry.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(700, 700), NO, 0.0);
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2, 2);
[myTextView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *text_image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I get this result when using above code:
[image: result]

Comment: If you're rendering your own text then you should be using Core Text not rendering the layer of a text view.

Comment: @Fogmeister I dont want to use core text.

Comment: Then don't be surprised when you get blurry text when you try to render layers like this :)

Comment: @Fogmeister there is no solution for this so ?

Comment: Why are you scaling the context?